# $_GET['variable'] into an Array Variable

Tags: php, arrays, get

Okay, so I have an array named with three values:

```
$tutorials = array('introduction', 'get_started', 'basics')
```

I also have a link for example:

```
mysite.com/?tutorials=get_started
```

So the link above appears to be the first value of $tutorials but what if I want my anchor's href to be like the next value?

```
<a href="?tutorials=basics">Next</a>
```

Are there any shortcuts for this? Because my array is not just only 3 but 20 and I don't want to edit them one by one.

What I'm trying to do here is a Next and Previous links. Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

   $value = $_GET['tutorials']; // get the current

   // find it's position in the array
   $key = array_search( $value, $tutorials );

   if( $key !== false ) {
      if( $key > 0 ) // make sure previous doesn't try to search below 0
          $prev_link = '?tutorials=' . $tutorials[$key-1];

      if( $key < count( $tutorials ) ) // Make sure we dont go beyond the end of the array
          $next_link = '?tutorials=' . $tutorials[$key+1];
   } else {
      // Some logic to handle an invalid key (not in the array)
   }

?>
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you! I just didn't know about array_search. Newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the index of the current item in your array, and add 1 to get the index of the following tutorial.

Don't forget to check if you already are on the latest item of the array.

```
<?php

$tutorials = array('introduction', 'get_started', 'basics');

$index = array_search($_GET['tutorials'], $tutorials);

if ($index === FALSE) {
    echo 'Current tutorial not found';
} else if ($index < count($tutorials) - 1) {
    echo '<a href="?tutorials=' . $tutorials[$index+1] . '">Next</a>';
} else {
    echo 'You are already on the latest tutorial available';
}
```

[Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Okay, I get it now. But I think there's a little mistake you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the key and add / minus one to the key to get the next / previous link:

```
$key = array_search($_GET['tutorials'], $tutorials);
```